# Jssor Slider Full Width Crashing on Iphone 6 Plus

Tags: jssor

I've encountered a problem with the full width slider. It crashes on Iphone 6 plus but it works on other devices. So far, Iphone 6 plus is the only device that it crashes on. It only crashes if the device is held portrait, but it works when it's held landscape.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: The full width slider had been well tested on iphone 6 plus. Would you please leave me an url that I can have a look?